# Calling fsincos instruction in LLVM slower than calling libc sin/cos functions?

Tags: assembly, llvm, inline-assembly, x87

I am working on a language that is compiled with LLVM. Just for fun, I wanted to do some microbenchmarks. In one, I run some million sin / cos computations in a loop. In pseudocode, it looks like this:

```
var x: Double = 0.0
for (i <- 0 to 100 000 000)
  x = sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2
return x.toInteger
```

If I'm computing sin/cos using LLVM IR inline assembly in the form:

```
%sc = call { double, double } asm "fsincos", "={st(1)},={st},1,~{dirflag},~{fpsr},~{flags}" (double %"res") nounwind
```

this is faster than using fsin and fcos separately instead of fsincos. However, it is slower than if I calling the `llvm.sin.f64` and `llvm.cos.f64` intrinsics separately, which compile to calls to the C math lib functions, at least with the target settings I'm using (x86_64 with SSE enabled).

It seems LLVM inserts some conversions between single/double precision FP -- that might be the culprit. Why is that? Sorry, I'm a relative newbie at assembly:

```
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %loopEntry1
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    $-1, %eax
    jmp     .LBB44_1
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB44_2:                               # %then4
                                    #   in Loop: Header=BB44_1 Depth=1
    movss   %xmm0, -4(%rsp)
    flds    -4(%rsp)
    #APP
    fsincos
    #NO_APP
    fstpl   -16(%rsp)
    fstpl   -24(%rsp)
    movsd   -16(%rsp), %xmm0
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtsd2ss        %xmm0, %xmm1
    movsd   -24(%rsp), %xmm0
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtsd2ss        %xmm0, %xmm0
    addss   %xmm1, %xmm0
.LBB44_1:                               # %loop2
                                    # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    incl    %eax
    cmpl    $99999999, %eax         # imm = 0x5F5E0FF
    jle     .LBB44_2
# BB#3:                                 # %break3
    cvttss2si       %xmm0, %eax
    ret
.Ltmp160:
    .size   main, .Ltmp160-main
    .cfi_endproc
```

Same test with calls to llvm sin/cos intrinsics:

```
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %loopEntry1
    pushq   %rbx
.Ltmp162:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    subq    $16, %rsp
.Ltmp163:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
.Ltmp164:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -16
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    $-1, %ebx
    jmp     .LBB44_1
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB44_2:                               # %then4
                                    #   in Loop: Header=BB44_1 Depth=1
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rsp)           # 8-byte Spill
    callq   cos
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)          # 8-byte Spill
    movsd   (%rsp), %xmm0           # 8-byte Reload
    callq   sin
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    addsd   8(%rsp), %xmm0          # 8-byte Folded Reload
.LBB44_1:                               # %loop2
                                    # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    incl    %ebx
    cmpl    $99999999, %ebx         # imm = 0x5F5E0FF
    jle     .LBB44_2
# BB#3:                                 # %break3
    cvttsd2si       %xmm0, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    ret
.Ltmp165:
    .size   main, .Ltmp165-main
    .cfi_endproc
```

Can you suggest how the ideal assembly would look like with fsincos? PS. Adding -enable-unsafe-fp-math to llc makes the conversions disappear and switches to doubles (fldl etc.), but the speed remains the same.

```
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:                                 # %loopEntry1
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    $-1, %eax
    jmp     .LBB44_1
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB44_2:                               # %then4
                                    #   in Loop: Header=BB44_1 Depth=1
    movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rsp)
    fldl    -8(%rsp)
    #APP
    fsincos
    #NO_APP
    fstpl   -24(%rsp)
    fstpl   -16(%rsp)
    movsd   -24(%rsp), %xmm1
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm1
    movsd   -16(%rsp), %xmm0
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
.LBB44_1:                               # %loop2
                                    # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    incl    %eax
    cmpl    $99999999, %eax         # imm = 0x5F5E0FF
    jle     .LBB44_2
# BB#3:                                 # %break3
    cvttsd2si       %xmm0, %eax
    ret
.Ltmp160:
    .size   main, .Ltmp160-main
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Hmm.. I think I'm starting to get it. fsin/fcos/fsincos use x87 registers and mulsd addsd use MMX / SSE. So the overhead is from moving the data between them probably?

Comment: No, `cvtsd2ss` is a conversion from double to float. But stay away from legacy coprocessor instructions, they are slower and more imprecise than library routines nowadays. See for instance http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-02/msg00188.html

Comment: And yes, there is additional overhead from moving, but it doesn't amount to much compared to the 200-300 cycles `fsincos` uses.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll stick with the llvm sin/cos intrinsics then.

Answer (score 22):

### Hardware trig is slow.

Too many documents claim that x87 instructions like `fsin` or `fsincos` are the fastest way to do trigonometric functions. Those claims are often wrong.

The fastest way depends on your CPU. As CPUs become faster, old hardware trig instructions like `fsin` have not kept pace. With some CPUs, a software function, using a polynomial approximation for sine or another trig function, is now faster than a hardware instruction.

In short, `fsincos` is too slow.

### Hardware trig is obsolete.

There is enough evidence that the x86-64 platform has moved away from hardware trig.

- amd64 prefers SSE over x87 for floats. Yet, SSE has no equivalents for x87 instructions like `fsin`.
- For amd64, libm in both [FreeBSD](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/msun/) and [glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree) implement sin() and such functions in software, not with x87 trig. glibc has [optimized x86-64 assembly for sinf()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/s_sinf.S;h=1529fb1f2452cefa1fdf482f8fa9165ffef4c197;hb=HEAD) (the single-precision sine) with a polynomial approximation, not with x87 `fsin`. [NetBSD](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libm/?only_with_tag=MAIN) and [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libm/) made the opposite choice: their libm for amd64 does use x87 instructions.
- Steel Bank Common Lisp uses `fsin` in its [x86 backend](http://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/master/tree/src/compiler/x86/float.lisp) but not in its x86-64 backend. For x86-64, SBCL compiles code that [calls sin() in libm](http://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/master/tree/src/code/irrat.lisp).

### Hardware trig loses the race.

I timed hardware and software sine on an AMD Phenom II X2 560 (3.3 GHz) from 2010.  I wrote a C program with this loop:

```c
volatile double a, s;
/* ... */
for (i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        s = sin(a);
```

I compiled this program twice, with two different implementations of sin(). The hard sin() uses x87 `fsin`. The soft sin() uses a polynomial approximation. My C compiler, `gcc -O2`, did not replace my sin() call with an inline `fsin`.

Here are results for sin(0.5):

```
$ time race-hard 0.5
    0m3.40s real     0m3.40s user     0m0.00s system
$ time race-soft 0.5
    0m1.13s real     0m1.15s user     0m0.00s system
```

Here soft sin(0.5) is so fast, this CPU would do soft sin(0.5) and soft cos(0.5) faster than one x87 `fsin`.

And for sin(123):

```
$ time race-hard 123
    0m3.61s real     0m3.62s user     0m0.00s system
$ time race-soft 123
    0m3.08s real     0m3.07s user     0m0.01s system
```

Soft sin(123) is slower than soft sin(0.5) because 123 is too large for the polynomial, so the function must subtract some multiple of 2π. If I also want cos(123), there is a chance that x87 `fsincos` would be faster than soft sin(123) and soft cos(123), for this CPU from 2010.

Comment: I confirm: Even on on my ageing Intel Xeon E5420, a million fSinCos assembly instruction takes 644 mS against System:Math.Sin+System.Math.Cos 101 mS

Answer (score 1):

`fsincos` is an x87 FPU instruction which operates on 80-bit precision floats. It doesn't support autovectorization but provides much higher precision than 64-bit instructions.

`sin` and `cos` operate on instructions with 64-bit precision so just lower precision will already make them faster. Code that executes on the FPU (`long double` 80 bit type) will never get autovectorized because that's not supported but regular 64 bit code(up to `double` type) will, so that can make it multiple times faster with SSE/AVX/NEON etc.

FPU should be only used when you actually need 80-bit precision. Saying that it's obsolete is not completly accurate. It's only obsolete in 99% cases and it's still needed in 1% cases.

To see `fsin` and `fcos` being generated by the compiler use `long double` type(80 bit float) with `sinl` `cosl` functions.